# How to clear part loaded operating system

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

Using a Noobs SD card I started to load my Raspberry Pi B+ for the fist time with Raspbian OS. Unfortunately I pulled the power cable mid operation as it was not the OS I wanted.
How do I start again and wipe what is there as a result of my stupidity?

Comment: assuming that pulling the power didn't corrupt the SD card, you can probably just restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry, it's easily done and the Pi is a pretty flexible tool for unplugging (unlike most PCs).

Sorting this is as easy as wiping the SD card and restoring NOOBS onto the SD card, then try installing it again.

**On a seperate Computer:**

- Stick the SD card into your computer of choice.
- **On Windows**: Double click on Computer
- Select the SD card.
- **On Mac OSX**: Double click on the SD card that appears on your desktop
- **On Linux**: (May vary depending on distribution and whether you are a text or graphical user). Navigate to your SD card using your File manager or the terminal. It should be under /home/[your name]/[Your SD Card].
- **All Platforms**: Select *everything* on the SD card and do Shift+Delete.
- Go back to https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/ to download a new copy of NOOBS (if you haven't already got it). Either version will work, but you'll need to keep your Pi connected to the internet for the whole network install as it won't tell you when it will/won't need it.
- Extract the contents of the file it gives you onto the card.

**Back on your Pi**

- Stick the SD card back into the slot and stick the power back in.
- Follow the instructions to install your OS of choice.
- Be happy :)

If you want a bit of help with NOOBs, don't forget the [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/) on the Raspberry Pi website is always a great tool.

Good luck with your endevours!

Comment: Thank you Mike you make it sound easy , then I have a chance of getting it right.R

Comment: You're most welcome :). Good luck and let us know how you get on.